# Qual é a diferença entre os operadores "+" e "&" quando na concatenação de strings?

Tags: string, vb.net, operadores, concatenação-de-string

No VB.NET, existem dois operadores que utilizo na concatenação de *strings*, o 
[`&`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wfx50zyk.aspx) e o [`+`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9c5t70w2.aspx) (sei que existem métodos mais eficientes para concatenar *strings*, porém nesta questão, me atento somente a esses dois operadores).

```
Dim Str1 As String = "Stack"
Dim Str2 As String = "overflow"

Console.WriteLine(Str1 & Str2)
Console.WriteLine(Str1 + Str2)
```

Veja funcionando no [.NET Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/l6pQ6L) ou no [Ideone](http://ideone.com/2oExAZ).

O retorno de ambos foi `Stackoverflow`, sem diferença prática alguma, ao meu ver.

No seguinte contexto, qual seria a diferença de usar o `&` e o `+`? E quais são os nomes desses operadores? Em qual caso devo usar cada um deles? Existem diferenças de legibilidade ou performance?

Comment: acredito que o `+` seja apenas um "atalho" pra concatenação ou apenas "outro jeito de fazer", tendo em vista que é um operador aritmético, e o `&` operador lógico, para junção, pelo pouco que achei no google tem um pequeno impacto na performance também, porem essa relação esta mais para quando se utiliza métodos como `concat()` onde umas serie de procedimentos devem ser realizados, o `+` é um operador aritmético para adição mesmo, enquanto o `&` operador lógico "and", numa sentença onde "A e B deve ser igual e do mesmo tipo que C" `A && B === C`

Comment: @HebertdeLima é VB.Net então nada disso vale.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Essencialmente não tem diferença. O `&` é o jeito VB de fazer a concatenação (é o estilo legado da linguagem quando ela era só VB). O `+` é o jeito VB.NET de fazer (foi adicionado à sintaxe para ficar mais próximo do C#, sua co-irmã). Então é gosto, só recomenda-se escolher um e usar sempre assim. Os dois convivem bem, na medida do possível.

Quem está acostumado com C#, e é comum a pessoa ter que lidar com C#, nem que seja em exemplos de código para .NET que tem bem mais para C# do que VB.NET, o `+` parece mais natural. Há quem não goste por ele poder ser confundido com operador aritmético. O que até faz algum sentido em VB que é dinamicamente tipado.

De fato pode haver alguma ambiguidade para o compilador quando usa o `+`, por isso costuma-se recomendar o `&`. Então o ideal é que sempre esteja usando [`Option Strict On`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/option-strict-statement?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397) para ser feliz.

Veja [a confusão no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/iyhmZk). E [no **.NET Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/TIaoDP). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/VB.NET/Concatenation2.vb).

Na minha concepção o `&` é errado até mesmo usando a opção estrita de conversão de tipos já que a concatenação faz a conversão. Pra mim é um motivo a mais para não usá-lo. Mas há gosto para tudo. Se acha confortável, é ok usar, só entenda as diferenças.

Veja [um pouco melhor no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/iZ1uKZ). E [no **.NET Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/j6xZTt). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/VB.NET/Concatenation.vb). (Strict On)

É claro que isso faz pouca diferença se considerar que a linguagem não foi criada para sistemas robustos. VB é mais uma dessas linguagens que começaram para fazer *scripts*. Quando surgiu a era das linguagens robustas para sistemas complexos ela foi se adaptando para atender essa nova demanda. Mas alguns vícios ficaram. Não há problema algum em adotar a linguagem. Mas tem que saber que terá que conviver com essas coisas.

Para algumas pessoas um é mais intuitivo que outro. O fato é que se a pessoa não tiver uma base de entendimento do que é a concatenação de *string* ambos são esquisitos. Se ela souber como funciona não importa muito qual o operador usado. `&` é usado apenas em VB.NET. O `+` é mais ou menos padrão na maioria das linguagens.

O uso normal não tem diferença de performance. Pode haver alguma diferença se um deles forçar alguma conversão de tipo. Mas aí está comparando coisas diferentes. A comparação só é justa para a mesma entrada e mesma saída.

Até onde sei eles não possuem nomes específicos. O genérico é operador de concatenação. Os símbolos tem nomes, mas sem contexto algum com essa pergunta.

Comment: Na verdade tem diferença sim. **&** é exclusivo para concatenação, enquanto **+** tem o propósito principal de somar números, podendo também fazer conversão de tipos seguida de concatenação se um dos operandos for string. O **&** continua a ser o padrão de concatenação mesmo em VB.Net, já que o outro tem função mais complexa em se tratando de concatenação e pode resultar em erros em tempo de execução dependendo do tipo e valor dos operandos. A documentação da Microsoft recomenda utilizar **&** para concatenação.

Comment: A pergunta é sobre concatenação de *strings*. Se fosse sobre operações diversas eu teria falado sobre isso. De qualquer forma eu coloquei no exemplo o que acontece quando se usa o operador `+` numérico. Por isso que eu prefiro usar `Option Strict On` e `+`, ele dá erro de compilação e não deixa fazer besteira. Usando `&` produz erros lógicos que são os piores porque podem passar desapercebidos.

Comment: @bigown Se não for abusar de sua boa vontade, acho que não ficou muito claro para mim a diferença de VB e VB.NET, citados no primeiro parágrafo. De resto, tudo certo, como sempre. Obrigado!

Comment: @ViníciusBrasil veja se ficou mais claro. No fundo o ideal é que só tivesse ficado um deles. Se foi adicionado é porque viram que teria algum benefício, talvez perceberam que poderiam dar maior robustez ao código dando uma nova semântica nos casos que precisa de conversão. Mas não poderiam mudar a semântica do operador existente. Criaram um novo.