# TextBox_Changed esta acumulando o valor da soma c#

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, textbox

Estou utilizando o evento `textBox_Changed` e quando digito um valor no campo, outro `textBox` deve receber esse valor, porém esse outro `textBox` chamado de `ValorTotalVenda` está acumulando este valor.

```
private void textBox4_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (textBox4.Text != "")
    {
         venda.ValorAcrescimo = Convert.ToDecimal(textBox4.Text);
         venda.ValorTotalVenda += venda.ValorAcrescimo;
         textBox6.Text = Convert.ToString(venda.ValorTotalVenda);
     }
}
```

Comment: Cara, no seu código não tem nenhum textBox chamado ValorTotalVenda. Tem uma propriedade (provavelmente Decimal) e você soma o valor da propriedade ValorAcrescimo. Se você quer que o textBox6 receba o valor digitado no textBox4 você deve fazer apenas `textBox6.Text = textBox4.Text`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Você está alterando o valor da propriedade ValorTotalVenda, não seria mais facil apenas somar os valores para o textbox6?
da maneira que esta escrita ou você define uma variavel global para o valor inicial da venda ou você faz deste jeito.

```
if (textBox4.Text != "")
        {
            venda.ValorAcrescimo = Convert.ToDecimal(textBox4.Text);
            textBox6.Text = Convert.ToString(venda.ValorTotalVenda + venda.ValorAcrescimo);
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

A cada caractere digitado no `textoBox4` é somado ao valor da variável `ValorTotalVenda`, o que me parece estranho.
Você pediu para exibir no textbox6 o valor somado, já que o [`operador +`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-BR/library/6a71f45d.aspx) com números irá realizar uma adição, e não uma concatenação.

```
private void textBox4_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (textBox4.Text != "")
        {
            venda.ValorAcrescimo = Convert.ToDecimal(textBox4.Text);
            venda.ValorTotalVenda += venda.ValorAcrescimo;
            //Mostra o valor somado
            textBox6.Text = venda.ValorTotalVenda.ToString();
            //ou, mostra inteiramente o conteúdo que está sendo digitado no textbo4
            textBox6.Text = textBox4.Text;
        }
    }
```

Além do código, veja esses posts como complementação:

[Qual é a diferença entre os operadores “+” e “&” quando na concatenação de strings?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/154231/qual-%C3%A9-a-diferen%C3%A7a-entre-os-operadores-e-quando-na-concatena%C3%A7%C3%A3o-de-strin)
[Qual o meio mais apropriado para se concatenar strings?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/124/qual-o-meio-mais-apropriado-para-se-concatenar-strings)